# PHP echo string containing variable

Tags: php, html, string, variables, echo

I have variable containing both text and variables (as text) such as the following

```
$variable = 'something';

$string = 'this is my string that contains a $variable in text form, but i want the variable to actually contain $variable when i echo it';
```

and what im trying to achieve is by echoing that string, it turns the variables into the correct text which would make the above sentence something like

```
echo $string;
```

should result in

> "this is my string that contains a something in text form, but i want
>   the variable to actually contain something when i echo it"

Thank you for any help

Edit.

I've tried double quotes like echo "$string"; however its still echos it as text.
im getting the variable via a simple query

```
$answer_id = $row0['id'];

<div class="text">
    <?php echo "$answer_id"; ?>
</div>
```

This still outputs a string without variables

Comment: its not a duplicate of that question as the answer didnt resolve my issue.

Comment: Your comment seems to show that you haven't even read the linked answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `double quotes`

```
$string = "this is my string that contains a $variable in text form, but i want the variable to actually contain $variable when i echo it";
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/PhEb1)

Comment: Also, concatenation of using methods/parameters you can encapsulate the variable with `{}` braces. IE: `echo "this is my string that contains a {$obj->getVariable()} in text form..."`

Comment: double quotes are the first thing i tried but its still echoing $variable as text

Comment: @Mystic check here https://3v4l.org/PhEb1

Comment: thank you for the demo, that exactly what i expected however i cant work out what im doing wrong, i will have to check my code